# How to get offset from thrust device_ptr in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Consider the following code:

```
thrust::device_ptr<uint> dev_ptr_keys(ptrCellIDs);

thrust::device_ptr<uint> dev_ptr_offset(ptrOffset);
thrust::pair<thrust::discard_iterator<>, thrust::device_ptr<uint>> end;

end = thrust::reduce_by_key(dev_ptr_keys, dev_ptr_keys + 10,
    thrust::make_constant_iterator(1), 
    thrust::make_discard_iterator(), 
    dev_ptr_offset, binary_pred, binary_op);
```

The `reduce_by_key` function in this case should create an array of offsets of equal values in the array the device pointer `dev_ptr_keys` points to and save it to the array at `dev_ptr_offset`. 
Therefore:

Intput (dev_ptr_keys): `{ 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1 }`

Output (dev_ptr_offset): `{ 1, 3, 2, 1 }`

So far, so good - however I also need to know the size of the new valid output array, which should be saved in `end.second`. But, I don't manage to get this information. I tried to play around with `thrust::raw_pointer_cast()`, but I don't manage to get the value neither within my kernel (by accessing the pointer wrapped by the thrust device pointer), nor in my host code.

How can I get the information of the size of my output in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, of all the things I tried the following was the last and it works the way I want:

```
uint numOffset = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&end.second[0]) - thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&dev_ptr_offset[0]);
```

On question remains: is this efficient at all, or does it even matter?

Comment: It is integer subtraction, run on the host. What possible "efficiency" issues could there be?

Comment: @talonmies The question of efficiency came from me being a CUDA newby and not knowing thrust that well. I was wondering if `thrust::raw_pointer_case()` copies data from the GPU to the host, which could create some overhead. I'm get what the thrust devicepointers do in general, but I'm not sure what happens in the background and if one can use them freely or should be careful with using them

Comment: raw_pointer_cast is exactly wheat it says --  a cast. There is no data transfer involved. In general, think of all pointers as unsigned integers with a tiny bit of metadata for the compiler to understand the type they point to (which is what they are) and not magical unicorns with amazing powers and properties (which they are not)